# Formula Field - AND Operation

Tags: apex, custom-object, standard-objects

I have created a formula field to calculate a score from other two fields. If the condition succeeds, the score will be a static value else the field value. The condition is

**`IF (AND (ISPICKVAL (object1,"object value"), VALUE (object2)=null), static value, VALUE (object2))`**

But the condition always fails even the scenario is correct. Is there any mistake in writing this formula? [Note: There is no syntax error when I hit "**Check Syntax**"]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the ISNULL() function instead of checking the Value(Object2)=null.

Change to this

```
ISNULL(VALUE(object2))
```

***EDIT***

As @Sdry points out, you could also use

```
ISBLANK(VALUE(object2))
```

ISBLANK() is a newer function, it has the same functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. So as Sdry points out, it is highly preferred over ISNULL().  ISNULL() will still work, just not the preferable function.

Comment: IsBlank() is highly prefered over isnull()

Comment: Agreed.  Edited the answer to reflect

Comment: IsBlank() makes the formula to work fine.